# Bootstrap Modal not working properly with my Rails logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-modal

I am having trouble getting my select box working properly inside my bootstrap-modal.

I am using Rails 4 and Bootstrap 3 and quite a few issues are taking place.

1. When I click on my "**Assign**" `button` my `modal` opens multiple times depending on how many records I currently have on the page.(ex.I have to click cancel 3 times to close my modal if I have 3 records in my table) I obviously just want my modal to open once.
2. When I select a "**manager**" from the `f.select` drop down box and then click "Assign" it changes the manager field of the 1st record and not the current record I am trying to assign. (If I have 3 records and click Assign on the 3rd record, it will update the manager field of the 1st record).

Here are some partial code snippets to show what I have done so far:

***index.html.erb***

```
<tbody>
 <% @projects.each do |project| %>

  <tr>
   <td><%= project.manager %></td>
   <td><%= project.subject %></td>
   <td><%= project.status %></td>

   <td>
     <% if controller.action_name == 'pending' %>

     <button type="button" class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".assign-modal">Assign</button>

     <div class="modal fade assign-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">

      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">

          <div class="modal-body">

              <%= render partial: 'new_assign', locals: {project: project} %>

          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>   
   </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
 </tbody>
```

***_new_assign.html.erb***

```
<div class="modal header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" <aria-hidden="true">x</button>
  <h3 id="myModalLabel">Assign a Manager</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 Manager(Project Manager)
 <%= form_for(project) do |f| %>
 <%= f.select :manager, [[""],["George"],["Thomas"],["Abe"],["Bill"]] %>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
 <%= f.submit "Assign", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:** The modal is popping because each loop is creating a new 'hidden' modal that is set to pop up when the trigger is pressed. So you need to isolate each modal and trigger to each other by assigning unique count/id vars to each. Here is how that works:

Update each modal trigger to have a unique id

`data-target=".assign-modal"` needs to change to something like `data-target="#modal-#{project.id}"`

and the modals themselves needs to do the same. So pull out the `.assign-modal` class and use ids for each modal. Something like:

`<div class="modal fade" id="modal-#{project.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" ...`

That will fix the multiple modal pop-up issue. On to issue 2!

**Issue 2:** The collection is broken. Just having `[[""],["George"],["Thomas"],["Abe"],["Bill"]]` as the collection doesn't allow for any 'value' to be assigned to the selected option. So it would probably be better to get a hash built up in the controller and send it down as an instance variable. Something like {1: "George", 2: "Thomas", 3: "Abe", etc} where the numbers are the manager's primary key ids.

That way when the form is submitted, it will send the params with a `params[:manager_id] = value of option selected` and will be super easy to use as in an associative way. Also, we don't need to have a blank/default as part of the collection. We can pass an option to the f.select to make that happen :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, as a quick note - spinning up multiple modals with multiples of the same form will work - but it would be much cooler to just have the button fire off an AJAX request to the new action. Then have the new method in the controller respond with a .js file that dynamically loads the form into a single modal and pops it up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issues you are seeing comes from the fact that you have included the modal inside your `@projects` loop. This means three records creates three modals with the same `assign-modal` class, all responding to the same button. I think this is also the cause of your second problem; Three modals are displayed when you click on the button for the third record. You’re then basically changing the manager of the first record, since the modal related to this record is the one in front.

Try moving the modal outside the loop, preferably outside the table.

Comment: Actually I don't think that's going to work. Putting it outside the loop will not allow me to assign a manager for each project. I think I might need to look into a collection_select or something with the id of the record to go with the id of the manager from the drop down list.